# Xcode 12.4 callers/callees menu location

Tags: xcode

How can I open that menu ? It seems "lovely" Xcode development team changed its location to elsewhere but I couldn't find. I don't understand why they keep making unnecessary "fixes" while there are certain major problems remain untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "4 little squares" icon in the top left corner of the editor:

[image]

There's also "Find Call Hierarchy" in the "Find" menu, Ctrl-Shift-Cmd-H

Comment: I know this sounds weird but I use this 4 square menu already, and there was something else inside this menu like "recently updated files". I closed Xcode and switched to another project before seeing your answer. Now this callers/callee menu come back I don't know what is happening.